# Change in schema.xml to disable stemming of similar sounding words

Tags: solr

I have to make some changes in my search application for which the existing code provides a way to display results which are also similar in pronounciation to the word entered to search, for eg. the user enters 'Julie', and the search results give 'July' as well. What change am I supposed to make in schema.xml for this? Basically I want to know hoe to turn off the stemming in such places.

P.S.I am a new bie, so please pardon my small doubt,I already tried googling all over. Thanks¬

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use solr.PhoneticFilterFactory for that and there are a few encoders available to use for this. I recommend DoubleMetaphone for this.

You can look [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PhoneticFilterFactory) for more details.

You need to define maybe a new field for the phonetic matching with a new type. 
So, step 1, define a new type

```
<fieldType name="phonetic" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="DoubleMetaphone" inject="false"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Step 2. use this type in a new field:

```
<field name="phoneticname" type="phonetic" multiValued="true" />
```

Step 3. add copy field to copy original name field into the phoneticname field

```
<copyField source="Name" dest="phoneticname"/>
```

Then in your search query, I suggest you search in both fields, name, and phoneticname with higher boost value on the original name, so you can get exact matches on name popped up search results, and phonetically matched names with a bit lower scores.

Comment: Thanks Emad, I'll try using that